# multidimensional array counting according to the value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, counting

```
$feetypes=[
    [30,35,50],
    [30,35],
    [30,50],
    [30,34]
];
```

i have this code, want to count as per there value like count 30*4, 35*2, 50*2 & 34*1.

i have already tried:

```
$counts = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$subarr) {
  // Add to the current group count if it exists
  if (isset($counts[$subarr['group']]) {
    $counts[$subarr['group']]++;
  }
  // or initialize to 1 if it doesn't exist
  else $counts[$subarr['group']] = 1;

  // Or the ternary one-liner version 
  // instead of the preceding if/else block
  $counts[$subarr['group']] = isset($counts[$subarr['group']]) ? $counts[$subarr['group']]++ : 1;
}
```

but my problem still there

Comment: Not sure where 'group' is coming from, but it looks like you could do this with another nested `foreach ($subarr as $subarrvalue) {`

Comment: WOW! Not sure how you select an answer, but good luck... https://3v4l.org/V2mWs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used recursion in case values are more than two levels deep. note the $count variable is passed by reference to the function due to recursion.

```
<?php
$feetypes=[
    [30,35,50],
    [30,35],
    [30,50],
    [30,34]
];

$counts = array();

function countValues($arr, &$count) {
    foreach($arr as $subval) {
        if(is_array($subval)) {
            countValues($subval,$count);
        } else {
            if(isset($count[$subval])) {
                $count[$subval] += 1;
            } else {
                $count[$subval] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

countValues($feetypes,$counts);
print_r($counts);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can merge all the inner arrays into one with `array_merge` and then use `array_count_values` to get the counts.

```
$counts = array_count_values(array_merge(...$feetypes));
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge all the subarray into a single array and apply `array_count_values` function to get the result

```
function merageAll($arr) {
  $flatArray = array();
  foreach($arr as $element) {
    if (is_array($element)) {
        $flatArray = array_merge($flatArray, merageAll($element));
    } else {
        $flatArray[] = $element;
    }
  }
  return $flatArray;
 }
 $res = array_count_values(merageAll($feetypes));
```

Result

```
Array
(
 [30] => 4
 [35] => 2
 [50] => 2
 [34] => 1
)
```

function merageAll work if there are values and sub arrays in the array.

Working [DEMO LINK](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/87176f17a14baa9b242d19476c03b068dd111c3b)